# Use npm install to deploy a node application?

Tags: node.js, npm

Say I have a node.js application (some web server for the manner of sake). So I have a directory structure with a `src` which contains my code and a `package.json` which includes some metadata about my project and all the packages needed to run it. So I run `npm install` to get all the packages and run `node server.js` to run the application.

I have a CI pipeline for my application that upon PR to master runs tests, and if succeeds, merges to master. The next step I want is to deploy the application on a server.

This means that eventually I need my source code plus all the dependencies on the server, and run `node server.js`.

Is it correct to publish my application as a package (as part of the CI pipeline), and then on the server run `npm install` to fetch it? Or is `npm install`ing packages only makes sense for packages that serve as some functionality for other applications?

The reason I doubt this is that when you run `npm install` (at least on a directory with a `package.json`) you get all the packages in the `node_modules` directory, which makes me believe that the second option I stated is true.

### NOTE

The application is running on a Windows server, no Dockers.

Comment: Running `npm install` again is not a disadvantage. It is mandatory. Your project will not only use the modules you have chosen on the first day of development. Maybe 3 years from now your project may need to use a new module. Forgetting to run `npm install` will break your app. Running `npm install` when you don't need to do it cost you only time (cheap) and does zero harm to your app.

Comment: @selbetman - please refer to the question after been edited.